# iPhone - avoid "more" tab from showing up in tab-based iPhone app

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to avoid the "more" tab to show up in my tab-based app? My app has 6 tabs and it feels stupid to have the More tab for just 1 extra tab.

Thanks.

Comment: designing a simpler interface is your only option. see: http://blogs.yankeegroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/small-simplicity.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe it's possible, other than writing your own UITabBar.